# reading a list of lines from a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text file and i am storing the values in a text file like this:

```
http://www.website.com/myurl1.php
http://www.website.com/myurl2.php
http://www.website.com/myurl3.php
http://www.website.com/myurl4.php
http://www.website.com/myurl5.php
http://www.website.com/myurl6.php
http://www.website.com/myurl7.php
```

Now With jquery when an refresh is done through any way, i want to call a function on body onload which will call this file and run the link one by one in ajax, rather than in actual url, so it should basically load the contents when it reaches the last file

hope my question make sense

Comment: Use ajax to read the file as well, keeping the list in the file as a json array would help more

Comment: can you show me something, i am noob in allt his

Comment: What have you tried already? I think what they are saying is that you can call over to a php file via an ajax request and have it do the execution for you. There is no need to do anything else in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax to read the file as well.
You can keep the list in the file as a json array to make things easier.
Lets name your file as list.json and put the list in json format:

```
['http://www.website.com/myurl1.php',
'http://www.website.com/myurl2.php',
'http://www.website.com/myurl3.php',
'http://www.website.com/myurl4.php',
'http://www.website.com/myurl5.php',
'http://www.website.com/myurl6.php',
'http://www.website.com/myurl7.php']
```

Using Jquery:

```
var myList = [];

$.get( "list.json", function( data ) {
  myList.append(data);
});
```

Iterate over myList to make each ajax call.
Hope this helps.

Comment: >> Iterate over myList to make each ajax call. Hope this helps. and how that i wil do, honestly i am a dumb in this

Comment: What I did in jquery is an ajax get call and 'list.json' is the url. so you will do the same for each url you get from this call in a loop over myList, for whatever purpose you have , for more info : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/